# Java Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY not working for 2.00 PM

Tags: java, calendar

I need to add two hours to current time and represent it in 24 hours format .
This is my code

```
public class Tester {

    @Test
    public void test() {

//for example i have entered time 12.00PM so it should add 2 hours and print 14.00
        System.out.println(stringToDate("2015-10-16 12:00:03"));


    }


    public static Date stringToDate(String str) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(str);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2);
            date = calendar.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
}


}
```

Expected Output

```
Fri Oct 16 14:00:03 IST 2015
```

But i got `Fri Oct 16 02:00:03 IST 2015`

If i use time `"2015-10-16 11:00:03"` instead of `"2015-10-16 12:00:03"`
Then i get correct output thats

```
"2015-10-16 13:00:03"
```

Please can anybody help me out to solve this

Comment: "HH" instead of "hh"?

Comment: @Thomas no thats not working it gives Sat Oct 17 02:00:03 IST 2015

Comment: And [12 AM is midnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), right?

Comment: No its 12.00 of noon 12.00 pm...Edited question to add that

Comment: Instead of `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2)`, shouldn't it be `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)` ?

Comment: Tried that too but has same results @FabioKenji

Comment: In the table, Wikipedia says "12-hour digital clocks with a.m. and p.m." midnight column: "12:00 a.m."

Comment: But if we use 24 hour format its 00.00AM and not 12.00.. 
I need to set 12.00 of noon to 14.00 thats my problem

Comment: make sure to correct this line `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2);` to be `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);`

Comment: hint: when dealing with dates, *always* be explicit about the timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method should look like this

```
public static Date stringToDate(String str) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(str);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        date = calendar.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;   
}
```

Comment: Yes its working i was making change at 1 but not at 8... thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is just wrong:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 2);
```

In this case you add the current hours plus 2 hours to the current hour. You should rather use:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
```

And for the 24h format: use `HH` instead of `hh`.

Answer (score 2):

change the hours format to 24Hour system (HH) instead of (hh) and the function Calendar.add adds 2 hours to the calendar time

```
public static Date stringToDate(String str) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(str);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        date = calendar.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: this is my output: Fri Oct 16 14:00:03 EET 2015